# Contact DataView

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, data-views

Does anyone know how to get a `Contact Builder` Contact ID, ContactKey using Query? Is there any **DataView** to get a Contact Builder Entire Population?

I don't see any documentation on the matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve Contact records from a query or AMPscript. You would need to use the REST API [Contacts Search method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/searchSchema.htm) to retrieve these values.

If you can provide some further detail on your use case, then I would be happy to expand my answer and provide possible solutions for you.

Comment: Thanks Eliot. I'd like to retrieve the MobilePush subscribers details so am using _PushAddress dataview and getting data successful; but may you know there is no ContactKey in _PushAddress table and I required ContactKey because same is PK in my multiple DEs so is there any way to get the ContactKey without using REST API?

Comment: I have some ideas how you can resolve this which I need to discuss with you. Send me an email at eliot.harper[at]salesforcemvps.com and we can arrange a brief webinar.

Comment: @EliotHarper Can you please share some ideas to resolve this ? Thanks!